# Changing position of UIProgressView?

Tags: swift, uiprogressview

I added a progress bar to my screen. I want it to be centered horizontally in my container, but I want to move it to the bottom of my screen. How do I edit the third line to change its position?

```
func addControls() {
    progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: UIProgressViewStyle.Default)
    progressView?.center = self.view.center
    view.addSubview(progressView!)
}
```

Comment: This will give you everything you need:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview

Comment: Yes, I have that - I just don't know how to structure the argument for the y-axis

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSLayoutConstraints and do something like this.  The 3rd line being where you put the progress bar on top or beneath the other object.

```
    var otherObject = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(progressView)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: progressView, attribute: .topMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: otherObject, attribute: .bottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: progressView, attribute: .leftMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leftMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: progressView, attribute: .rightMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .rightMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: progressView, attribute: .bottomMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
    self.view.addConstraints([topConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint, bottomConstraint])
```

Answer (score 0):

That's really simple.

If you want to add a subview above another one, use [this function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622570-insertsubview):

```
func insertSubview(_ view: UIView, aboveSubview siblingSubview: UIView)
```

To add a subview below another one, use [this function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622598-insertsubview):

```
func insertSubview(_ view: UIView, belowSubview siblingSubview: UIView)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! I don't really want to add it as a subview, though - I'd rather have it as a fixed location that just happens to be below another object on my screen. (The object above moves, so it's really just for the start.)